# How do I include 2 file uploads in the same form and then insert them into a MYSQL database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering this since I already tried this but it didn't work. I didn't recieve any errors yet the data was not added to the MYSQL table, so I came here to hopefully find out what the problem is since I couldn't fine any answers.
Here's the code:

```
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    echo "You have already created a BSW!";
} else {
    echo
    '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;" type="text" name="name" placeholder="BSW Name"><br>
        <textarea style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px; width: 200px; height: 80px;" type="text" name="powers" placeholder="BSW Powers (seprated by commas)"></textarea><br>
        <textarea style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px; width: 200px; height: 80px;" type="text" name="weaknesses" placeholder="BSW Weaknesses (seprated by commas)"></textarea><br>
        <textarea style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px; width: 250px; height: 80px;" type="text" name="about" placeholder="BSW About (seprated by commas)"></textarea><br>
        <strong>Are you currently available?</strong>
        <select name="available">
            <option name="yes">yes</option>
            <option name="no">no</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <strong>Icons bigger than 100x100 will be rescaled</strong><br>
        <input style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;" type="file" name="icon" multiple><br>
        <strong>Demonstration (Only supports swf and mp4 filetypes): </strong><br>
        <input style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;" type="file" name="demo" multiple><br><br>
        <strong>Demo Filetype (Select none if you do not have a demo)</strong><br>
        <select name="filetype">
            <option name="mp4">mp4</option>
            <option name="swf">swf</option>
            <option name="none">none</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <button style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;" type="submit" name="bsw">Submit BSW</button><br>
    </form>';
    }
} else {
    echo "Please login.";
}

if (isset($_POST['bsw'])) {
    $name1 = str_replace("<","&lt;",$_POST['name']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name1);

    $powers1 = str_replace("<","&lt;",$_POST['powers']);
    $powers = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $powers1);

    $weaknesses1 = str_replace("<","&lt;",$_POST['weaknesses']);
    $weaknesses = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $weaknesses1);

    $about1 = str_replace("<","&lt;",$_POST['about']);
    $about = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $about1);

    $available1 = str_replace("<","&lt;",$_POST['available']);
    $available = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $available1);

    $iconDir = "files/uploads/bsw/icons/";
    $iconName = basename($_FILES['icon']['name']);
    $iconTemp = $_FILES['icon']['tmp_name'];
    $iconError = $_FILES['icon']['error'];
    $iconType = explode('.', $iconName);
    $iconActualType = strtolower(end($iconType));
    $iconAllowed = array('png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif');

    $owner = $user->data['username'];
    $ownerId = $user->data['user_id'];

    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');

    $demoDir = "files/uploads/bsw/demos/";
    $demoName = basename($_FILES['demo']['name']);
    $demoTemp = $_FILES['demo']['tmp_name'];
    $demoError = $_FILES['demo']['error'];
    $demoType = explode('.', $demoName);
    $demoActualType = strtolower(end($demoType));
    $demoAllowed = array('swf', 'mp4');

    if (empty($name) || empty($powers) || empty($weaknesses) || empty($about) || empty($iconName)){
        echo '<p style="color: red; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">Please Fill in All Fields</p>';
    } else {
        if(!in_array($iconActualType, $iconAllowed)) {
            if($iconError === 0) {
                $iconNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$iconActualType;
                $iconDestination = $iconDir . $iconNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($iconTemp, $iconDestination);
                if(!in_array($demoActualType, $demoAllowed)) {
                    if($fileError === 0) {
                        $demoNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$demoActualType;
                        $demoDestination = $demoDir . $demoNameNew;
                        move_uploaded_file($demoTemp, $demoDestination);
                    }
                    if (mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `bsw`
                            (`bsw_name`, `bsw_about`, `bsw_points`, 
                             `bsw_demo_location`, `bsw_power`, 
                             `bsw_weaknesses`, `bsw_icon_location`, 
                             `bsw_availability`, `bsw_owner`, 
                            `bsw_owner_id`, `bsw_type`)
                        VALUES('$name', '$about', '0', 
                               '$demoDestination', '$powers', '$weaknesses',
                                '$iconDestination', '$available', 
                                '$owner', '$ownerId', '$demoFiletype')")) {
                        echo '';
                    } else {
                        echo "Error: <br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance, any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: What debugging have you done to try to narrow down the issue?

Comment: pass name in input type file as an array of inputs, like `<input type = "file" name = "file[demo]" />` and `<input type = "file" name = "file[icon]" />` then read the `$_FILES['file']` as  multidimensional array

Comment: If you use `multiple` on a `type=file` your `$_FILES` is an array of arrays. [Read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: If you only want to upload **2** files from different fields then **remove the multiple option from both**

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: `'$owner', '$ownerId', '$demoFiletype')")) {` Why is there an `{` on that line

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks! also there's an `{` due to it being an `if` statement.

Comment: Oh yea! Ouch thats ugly

Comment: I tried cleaning up some of the code but neither are the files getting uploaded or the data being sent to the DB. Any help?